# C++ аргумент шаблона не может ссылаться на не являющуюся внешней сущность

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T, int size, const char* random>
auto statik()
{
    static T t[size];
    return t;
}

int main()
{ 
     statik<int, 10, __TIME__>(); // error
}
```

> аргумент шаблона не может ссылаться на не являющуюся внешней сущность

Как можно исправить?

Comment: Строковые литералы нельзя использовать в качестве параметров шаблонов. Передавать char * в качестве аргумента функции.

Comment: ok спасиб буду знать

Comment: Как вариант, В 20 стандарте можно передавать строку как массив `template<typename T, int size, ::std::array<char, 9> random>` `statik<int, 10, {__TIME__}>();`  https://godbolt.org/z/f9ccxnTxj